# tornado timeout on to much recursive requests

Tags: python, tornado, coroutine

I am trying to test async processing in tornado and I wrote an HTTP server for calculating fibonacci numbers over recursive HTTP calls.
It works for small numbers like 6 but hangs at 8.
I am sure that async works here because otherwise it would stuck at n = 3.
I cannot explain why it stuck at 8. Fibonacci grows fast but for 8 it's still not much deep to exhaust ports or open file handlers.

What is an obstacle here?

python 2.7 and tornado 4.3

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web
from tornado import gen
from tornado.httpclient import AsyncHTTPClient

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    @gen.coroutine
    def get(self):
        n = int(self.get_argument('n', 1))
        print 'n = ', n
        if n <= 2:
            self.write("1")
        else:
            npUrl = 'http://localhost:8888/?n=%s' % (n - 1)
            nppUrl = 'http://localhost:8888/?n=%s' % (n - 2)
            print " get np %s an npp %s " % (npUrl, nppUrl)
            np, npp = yield [ self.http_client.fetch(npUrl),
                              self.http_client.fetch(nppUrl) ]
            npAndNpp = int(np.body) + int(npp.body)
            print 'np + npp  = %s + %s = %s' % (np.body, npp.body, npAndNpp)
            self.write("%s" % npAndNpp)
#        raise tornado.gen.Return(None)

def make_app():
    return tornado.web.Application([
        (r"/", MainHandler),
    ])

app = make_app()
app.listen(8888)
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Log output

```
egnyte@diehard:~/demo/tornado$ python async-fibonacci.py 
n =  7
 get np http://localhost:8888/?n=6 an npp http://localhost:8888/?n=5 
n =  6
 get np http://localhost:8888/?n=5 an npp http://localhost:8888/?n=4 
n =  5
 get np http://localhost:8888/?n=4 an npp http://localhost:8888/?n=3 
n =  5
 get np http://localhost:8888/?n=4 an npp http://localhost:8888/?n=3 
n =  4
 get np http://localhost:8888/?n=3 an npp http://localhost:8888/?n=2 
n =  4
 get np http://localhost:8888/?n=3 an npp http://localhost:8888/?n=2 
n =  3
 get np http://localhost:8888/?n=2 an npp http://localhost:8888/?n=1 
n =  4
 get np http://localhost:8888/?n=3 an npp http://localhost:8888/?n=2 
n =  3
 get np http://localhost:8888/?n=2 an npp http://localhost:8888/?n=1 
n =  3
 get np http://localhost:8888/?n=2 an npp http://localhost:8888/?n=1 
n =  2
n =  3
 get np http://localhost:8888/?n=2 an npp http://localhost:8888/?n=1 
n =  7
 get np http://localhost:8888/?n=6 an npp http://localhost:8888/?n=5 
ERROR:tornado.application:Multiple exceptions in yield list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 789, in callback
    result_list.append(f.result())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
HTTPError: HTTP 599: Timeout
ERROR:tornado.application:Multiple exceptions in yield list
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 789, in callback
    result_list.append(f.result())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
HTTPError: HTTP 599: Timeout
ERROR:tornado.application:Multiple exceptions in yield list
```

Comment: Did you try to change ```max_clients``` (10 is default) for AsyncHTTPClient ?

Comment: max_clients helped me to reach n=14. My ulimit 1000. Such a low default value makes me think that the lib has problems.

Comment: We changed ```max_clients``` to 1000 per worker. This limit is creating queue of 10 concurrent outgoing connections. And if they are taking long then connections are timeouting when they are already in that queue.

Answer (score 2):

Your program's recursion requires Tornado to keep more than ten HTTP requests in progress simultaneously, but by default AsyncHTTPClient's max_clients is 10.

When you begin the 11th request your program deadlocks: it needs to start a new HTTP request in order to complete the Fibonacci calculation, but it cannot start a new request until one of the current requests finishes.

You can see this in action if you add these lines:

```
import tornado.options
tornado.options.parse_command_line()
```

And start your program with `--logging=debug`. Eventually your program logs:

```
[D 160326 12:03:16 simple_httpclient:137] max_clients limit reached, request queued. 10 active, 11 queued requests.
```

...then deadlocks. Twenty seconds later, AsyncHTTPClient's default timeout throws an exception.

You can support higher levels of recursion by running this at the beginning of your program:

```
AsyncHTTPClient.configure(None, max_clients=100)
```